# What is the difference between image2d_t and image2d_array_t in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

What is the difference between image2d_t and image2d_array_t data types in OpenCL? 
I couldn't find much information in the specification.

Comment: 2d_array_t must be separate images and 3d must be more optimized in hardware for filtering inter-image pixels so computing images separately, array_t may be better and computing them together, 3d could be better. But I did not try these, just an assumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`image2d_t` is a flat 2D image of a specific format and size. It may also contain mipmap levels if the `cl_khr_mipmap_image` extension is available (https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_mipmap_image.html).

`image2d_array_t` is an array of images that are all of the same size and type. Take a look at https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/cl_image_desc.html for how to create such an image array. From this page:

> Note that reading and writing 2D image arrays from a kernel with image_array_size = 1 may be lower performance than 2D images.

so you should only use image arrays when needed.

See https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/read_imagef2d.html for how to access `image2d_t` and `image2d_array_t` from your kernels. For image arrays, the index of the image required will be in the `z` texture coordinate. For both `image2d_t` and `image2d_array_t` the mipmap level is specified as the `lod` parameter to `read_image()`.

Image arrays are useful if you need to pass an variable number of images to a kernel, i.e. decided at run-time, as in your kernel you can query how many images there are in an `image2d_array_t` with `get_image_array_size()`, e.g. say you wanted to average together all the images in the image array.

They are also useful for indexing images from within your kernel, e.g. selecting an edge sharpening mask (stored in the image array) based on the local image statistics calculated in your kernel.

In hardware, `image2d_array_t` are usually faster than `image3d_t` and more widely supported. However, `image2d_array_t` cannot (automatically) sample *between* array images whereas `image3d_t` can sample at fractional `z` locations.